# unit test an attached behavior wpf

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, attachedbehaviors

I am still grokking attached behaviors in general, and am at a loss to see how to write a unit test for one.

I pasted some code below from Sacha Barber's Cinch framework that allows a window to be closed via attached behavior. Can somewone show me an example unit test for it?

Thanks!
Berryl

```
    #region Close

    /// <summary>Dependency property which holds the ICommand for the Close event</summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Close",
            typeof(ICommand), typeof(Lifetime),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnCloseEventInfoChanged));

    /// <summary>Attached Property getter to retrieve the CloseProperty ICommand</summary>
    public static ICommand GetClose(DependencyObject source)
    {
        return (ICommand)source.GetValue(CloseProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>Attached Property setter to change the CloseProperty ICommand</summary>
    public static void SetClose(DependencyObject source, ICommand command)
    {
        source.SetValue(CloseProperty, command);
    }

    /// <summary>This is the property changed handler for the Close property.</summary>
    private static void OnCloseEventInfoChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var win = sender as Window;
        if (win == null) return;

        win.Closing -= OnWindowClosing;
        win.Closed -= OnWindowClosed;

        if (e.NewValue == null) return;

        win.Closing += OnWindowClosing;
        win.Closed += OnWindowClosed;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is invoked when the Window.Closing event is raised.  
    /// It checks with the ICommand.CanExecute handler
    /// and cancels the event if the handler returns false.
    /// </summary>
    private static void OnWindowClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var dpo = (DependencyObject)sender;
        var ic = GetClose(dpo);
        if (ic == null) return;

        e.Cancel = !ic.CanExecute(GetCommandParameter(dpo));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is invoked when the Window.Closed event is raised.  
    /// It executes the ICommand.Execute handler.
    /// </summary>
    static void OnWindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dpo = (DependencyObject)sender;
        var ic = GetClose(dpo);
        if (ic == null) return;

        ic.Execute(GetCommandParameter(dpo));
    }

    #endregion
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would likely use a lambda in your `ICommand` using a `DelegateCommand` or a `RelayCommand`. Multiple implementations of these exists all over the place and Cinch may have something similar. Really simple version (as an example, not meant for production use):

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand {
    private Action _execute = null;

    public void Execute( object parameter ) {
        _execute();
    }

    public DelegateCommand( Action execute ) {
        _execute = execute;
    }

    #region stuff that doesn't affect functionality
    public bool CanExecute( object parameter ) {
        return true;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged {
        add { }
        remove { }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Then your test body might look something like this:

```
bool wascalled = false;

var execute = new DelegateCommand(
    () => {
        wascalled = true;
    } );

var window = new Window();
SomeClass.SetClose( window, execute );

// does the window need to be shown for Close() to work? Nope.

window.Close();

AssertIsTrue( wascalled );
```

This is an over-simplified example. There are of course other tests you'll want to perform, in which case you should create or find a fuller implementation of `DelegateCommand` that also properly implements `CanExecute`, among other things.

Comment: cinch goes a step further with the RelayCommand by baking your wascalled test into a CommandSucceeded bool property. Your post is helpful in enforcing that SetClose is still a property setter at the end of the day, even if it doesn't look like the simpler normal C# property setters! That is one of the things I wasn't seeing and isn't intuitive for me yet about DP/attached behavior. Cheers

Comment: Yep. When compiled, those static Get/Set methods are called. Same thing with DPs: it skips the property wrapper and directly calls `SetValue`/`GetValue` on the `DependencyObject`. Good to hear of that in Cinch. It isn't one I've perused yet.

Answer (score 3):

DependencyProperty changing and value coercion on their own looks like 'Impossible Dependencies' for me. Having reference to Window there makes things even trickier. I think I'd go with [Humble Object pattern](http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html) here...

Comment: I can actually live with the window in this case, but that is an interesting link. Can you illustrate how you would apply the Humble Object Pattern in this case? Cheers